# Continously link the log file with external file which contains only grep values

Tags: linux, bash

I have a log file /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log and I am trying to see the file with some selected data as follows

```
tail -f /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log | grep --line-buffered openerp.addons.service_logger.service_logger
```

But instead of giving this command every-time, is there any other way to link it to other file with continuous grepped output of above file. sot that I can only view data data with the lines whenever I open this file.

In other words, we are creating the duplicate file for the above log file with only specific lines grepped continously.

Answer (score 1):

You could use screen to set it as a background process.

put it in a quick script and run it with `screen -A -m -d -S MyLogger /path/to/script`

This will put it in a "background process" called MyLogger that you can connect to with `screen -r MyLogger` and exit by detaching with `ctrl+a ctrl+d` .... see a list of screens by doing screen -ls.

Hope this helps!!